# Reuse the tab of a component in another component except a widget in touch ui aem

Tags: aem, sightly

I have a component /apps/myproject/component1.
In its dialog i have some widgets.Now I have another component /apps/myproject/component2 and its dialog want to use the same tab but a widget should be removed and one should be added in component2 touch UI dialog in AEM.
I tried to achieve it using 
`sling:resourceType :"granite/ui/components/foundation/include"
path:"/apps/myproject/component1"` 
on tab1.
But if i want to add and remove a widget, i am not able to do that.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Which version of AEM are you using? You can use Sling Resource Merger for `sling:superResourceType` since 6.1 and you can add or remove some properties and nodes that way.

Some documentation : https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/platform/sling-resource-merger.html

Comment: Thank you so much @Bambara.